# Laravel 5.0 - Generate PDF from template and add data

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

This is the case:

I have a **form** where the user has to fill in **5 fields**. I also have a **PDF template** with some layout with **5 empty colored boxes**.

Now when the user fills in the form a **PDF should be generated from the pdf template** and the fields that the user has given in should be **added to the template**.

Now my question what's the best and easiest way to do this? I've look at the library [laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) but it didn't look like it's working with templates.

Did anybody had to do this? If yes, how did you do it? I'm working with laravel **5.0** .

Answer (score 2):

I've used the packages [fpdf](https://packagist.org/packages/itbz/fpdf) and [fpdi](https://packagist.org/packages/itbz/fpdi) to work with pdf templates.

Answer (score 2):

I use the "vsmoraes/laravel-pdf": "^1.0" package and it does well for us.

```
use Vsmoraes\Pdf\Pdf;

private $pdf;

public function __construct(Pdf $pdf)
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->pdf = $pdf;
}
public function pdfMaker($data)
{
$html = view('pdf.shippinglabel')->with('purchase', $purchase)->with('products', $products)->render();

    $label = $this->pdf->load($html)->output();

    file_put_contents(storage_path()."/ftp/po/label_".$id.".pdf",$label);
}
```

And then I have the formatted pdf with embedded CSS and not including external CSS file linking.

here's the github url: https://github.com/vsmoraes/pdf-laravel5

Answer (score 1):

Dompdf doesn't work with pdf templates, but it works with HTML templates.

So, you can do this way:

- Prepare a HTML template and place some placeholders( i.e: `{field1}`, `{field2}`, ecc )  where you want to print the values you'll get from the form
- When the form is submitted, load the html template into a string, replace the placeholders in the string with the actual values you got from the form
- Pass the string (that will contain valid html) to dompdf and it will generate a PDF file

Comment: Thanks @Moppo for your solution, please could you set the code to see how can I use it

Answer (score 1):

With the Laravel package from Barry (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) you can load views. So in that way it is possible to make a template using the Blade views.